# Upgrading SpringBoot from 2.3.9 to 2.4.3 breaks my tests which uses soft delete (with @Where)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, spring-data-jpa

I had upgraded SpringBoot (2.3.9 to 2.4.3) on my project but my tests failed (8 of 2000).
Theses tests are almost all concerning soft deleting like :

```
  var myobjectDatabase = getAMyobjectDatabase();
  myobjectDatabaseRepository.save(myobjectDatabase);

  // When
  myobjectDatabaseRepository.softDelete(myobjectDatabase);
  var myobjectRetrieved = myobjectDatabaseRepository.getById(myobject.getId());

  // Then
  assertThat(myobjectRetrieved).isNull(); // ERROR
```

So I had investigate and if I add `entityManager.clear()` between the `softDelete` and the `getById`, it works !
The same if I add `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)`.

But I don't like these "quickfix". I had read the changelogs but nothing about that.

Anyone can help me or change my mind ?

Thanks !

Comment: I'm surprised it even worked in the first place. This happens due to the first level cache and not doing a `flush` and `clear` in between to simulate a transaction ending. The only thing I can imagine that changed is that your test is now transactional where it first was not.

Comment: Hello @M.Deinum, firstly, thank you for your fast response !
Do you know why it doesn't appears in the changelog or in the migration ? (maybe I have missed it)
As you said, I checked the tests' logs and effectively, it emerge that the tests are now transactional.